# Is there any way to delete the rows of data which don't have all numeric values?

Tags: r, numeric, data-cleaning

I have data that has two columns. Each column of data has numerical values in it but some of them don't have any numerical values. I want to remove the rows which don't have all values numerical. In reality, the data has 1000 rows but for simplification, I made the data file in smaller size here. Thanks!

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, "--")
b <- c("--", 2, 3, "--", 5)
data <- data.frame(a, b)
```

Comment: In your example, all rows have at least one numeric value. Do you mean all values must be numeric?

Comment: - @tmfmnk, yes all values must be numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `base R` option could be:

```
data[!is.na(Reduce(`+`, lapply(data, as.numeric))), ]

  a b
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

And for importing the data, use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

Or using `sapply()`:

```
data[!is.na(rowSums(sapply(data, as.numeric))), ]
```

Answer (score 2):

An easier option is to check for `NA` after converting to `numeric` with `as.numeric`.  If the element is not numeric, it returns `NA` and that can be detected with `is.na` and use it in `filter_all` to remove the rows

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    filter_all(all_vars(!is.na(as.numeric(.))))
#  a b
#1 2 2
#2 3 3
```

If we don't like the warnings, an option is to detect the numbers only element with regex by checking one or more digits (`[0-9.]+`) including a dot from start (`^`) to end (`$`) of string with `str_detect`

```
library(stringr)
data %>% 
    filter_all(all_vars(str_detect(., "^[0-9.]+$")))
#  a b
#1 2 2
#2 3 3
```

---

If we have only `--` as non-numeric, it is easier to remove

```
data[!rowSums(data == "--"),]
#  a b
#2 2 2
#3 3 3
```

#### data

```
data <- data.frame(a,b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: @tmfmnk, I ran the code and the result was the same. But I used the filter_all function that you used and it worked. Thank you :-)
filter_all(data,all_vars(. != "--"))

Comment: @Nini you may need to update the data i.e. `data <- data %>%
    filter_all(all_vars(!is.na(as.numeric(.))))`